# Getting Stripe working in Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, stripe-payments

I am trying to set up stripe in rails and I can enter in the credit card info but when it redirects I get the following error:

```
No route matches [POST] "/enrollment/1"
```

I am confused because when I rake routes I get:

```
 enrollment_index GET    /enrollment(.:format)                                 enrollment#index
                  POST   /enrollment(.:format)                                 enrollment#create
   new_enrollment GET    /enrollment/new(.:format)                             enrollment#new
  edit_enrollment GET    /enrollment/:id/edit(.:format)                        enrollment#edit
       enrollment GET    /enrollment/:id(.:format)                             enrollment#show
                  PATCH  /enrollment/:id(.:format)                             enrollment#update
                  PUT    /enrollment/:id(.:format)                             enrollment#update
                  DELETE /enrollment/:id(.:format)                             enrollment#destroy
```

So I am confused why it is trying to post because in my view, I specify that the method should be put:

```
 <div class='container'>
        <div class='jumbotron enroll-page'>
            <div class='row'>
                <h1>Enroll Here</h1>
                <%= form_tag enrollment_path(1), :method => :put do %>
                  <article>
                    <label class="amount">
                      <span>Amount: $5.00</span>
                    </label>
                  </article>

                  <script src="https://checkout.stripe.com/checkout.js" class="stripe-button"
                          data-key="<%= Rails.configuration.stripe[:publishable_key] %>"
                          data-description="A month's subscription"
                          data-amount="500"></script>
                <% end %>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

My controller looks like this:

```
class EnrollmentController < ApplicationController
    before_filter :authenticate_user!, unless: :admin_signed_in?

    def new
    end

    def create
        #get credit card details submitted by form
        token = params[:stripeToken]

        customer = Stripe::Customer.create(
            :card => token,
            :plan => 3455,
            :email => current_user.email
        )

        current_user.paid = true
        current_user.stripeid = customer.id
        current_user.save

        redirect_to courses_path, :notice => 'Your enrollment is complete!'
    end
end
```

Thanks so much for any help that you can give!

EDIT: I think I have it. Ajay was totally right that this works better if I name the controller "enrollments" instead of enrollment.  In the new.html.erb view, it should look like this instead:

```
<div class='container'>
    <div class='jumbotron enroll-page'>
        <div class='row'>
            <h1>Enroll Here</h1>
            <%= form_tag enrollments_path do %>
              <article>
                <label class="amount">
                  <span>Amount: $5.00</span>
                </label>
              </article>

              <script src="https://checkout.stripe.com/checkout.js" class="stripe-button"
                      data-key="<%= Rails.configuration.stripe[:publishable_key] %>"
                      data-description="A month's subscription"
                      data-amount="500"></script>
            <% end %>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check in routes the resource must be enrollments not enrollment

```
 #routes.rb
resources :enrollments
```

Now when you run

```
rake routes | grep 'enrollment'
new_enrollment  GET   /enrollments/new(.:format)  enrollments#new

#app/controller/enrollments_controller.rb

class EnrollmentsController < ApplicationController
  def new 
   @enrollment = Enrollment.new 
  end

  def edit
    @enrollment = Enrollment.where(id: params[:id]).first 
  end

  def create 
    #catch your params and do whatever. 
  end

  def update
    # catch your params and do your operation.
   end
end
```

Now comes the View :

```
app/views/enrollments/new.html.erb 
 <%= render 'form %> 
app/views/enrollments/edit.html.erb
<%= render 'form' %>
```

now in your app/views/enrollments/_form.html.erb

```
 <%= form_tag(@enrollment)do %>

   <%= label_tag :amount %> 
   <%= text_field_tag :amount, 50.00 %> 

   <%= submit_tag %> 
 <% end %>
```

In your console, the log should be something like this :

```
Started GET "/enrollments/new" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-01-10 06:18:08 +0530
Processing by EnrollmentsController#new as HTML
```

This confirms you are hitting the new page not the edit. Check it !

Inspect your form, this should look like this, check it.
[image: Y]

Comment: Thanks for the response! I tried switching over to enrollments to start for the controller, routes, and view and I seem to have gotten a little further.   Now it says there isn't an update action though, why does it need that?

Comment: As you had put your code in create action so I assumed you were trying to create a record. As your error complains about update action, then you must be trying to update some record.

Comment: Hmm strange, I am definitely trying to create a record. I wonder what in the code is making it think that I am trying to update it.  Thanks again!

Comment: Welcome, please consider accepting this answer if this has fixed your issue.

Comment: Thanks! Unfortunately I am still getting that update action cannot be found.

Comment: Then you are in enrollment edit page. Now, in your controller try adding the def update action. that will help.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. The only views I have are create and new. The only controller actions are new and create too. I can't figure out where it is getting the edit page at all.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/68529/discussion-between-ajay-and-coherent).